# Applying patch file to ubuntu server

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, tcp, patch

Can someone please explain how to apply a patch file to ubuntu server kernel? I'm trying to apply [this](https://github.com/cloudflare/linux) patch file which enables the `tcp_collapse_max_bytes` option in the TCP communication options on an ubuntu server. I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659867/559093) answer and tried to apply the `.patch` but got the same error.

Here are my steps:
first, I changed the directory to the kernel source folder:

`cd /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic`

Then I run the command `patch -p0 ~/file.patch`

But I got the following info and it keeps asking me to enter the file to patch

```
can't find file to patch at input line 44
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
...
...
File to patch:
```

I think I am working in wrong directory but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to download the source code and patch the downloaded source code. For some reason that I don't know exactly, the codes in `/usr/src/` were not the exact code of the official Linux. (Probably my VPS provider modified them).
I followed [these](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html) steps and applied the patch after downloading the codes, then compiled the kernel and installed it.

So, the following steps helped me:

1. Download the corresponding linux kernel source code, from official websites such as [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)
2. Extract the kernel and change the directory, i.e. `cd linux-5.15.**`
3. Apply the patch `patch -p1 < path/to/patch/0014-add-a-sysctl-to-enable-disable-tcp_collapse-logic.patch`
4. Compile the patched kernel and install it. This step may be slightly different based on the distributions, and also requires some dependencies. but usually involves the following commands :

`make menuconfig`

`make`

Note that step 4 may be different based on the linux distribution and may require installing some other packages to compile and install the kernel.

Comment: I've added more Information.

Comment: Excellent, mate :-) I deleted my comment.